# Apache configured to listen on port 80 only but instead listening on port 8080 as well

Tags: apache

I was not able to use port 8080 because it was apparently already used.

In order to see which program was using it, I typed the following command in my terminal (on MacOS):

```
   sudo lsof -n -i :8080
```

Here's the result:

[image]

httpd is also listening on port 80, which I found out by using the following command:

```
sudo lsof -n -i :80 | grep LISTEN
```

Here's the result:

[image]

So I went to find out what this "httpd"-process was. Apparently it is basically  the web server installed on my machine. The web server installed on my machine is Apache2.

Given this fact I concluded that Apache2 was apparently configured to listen on port 80 AND on port 8080.

BUT: Here's the crazy thing: I went to the folder /etc/apache2 and opened the file "httpd.conf". In the file Apache is configured to listen on port 80 only !!!

Why the hell is it also listening on port 8080 ?!

How can I make it listen on port 80 only ?

Comment: Does your httpd.conf contain any 'Include' directives?

Comment: Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

Comment: Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

Comment: Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf

Comment: Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf

Comment: ... these are the ones that were not commented out

Comment: Take a look at those files - maybe there you have instructions for listening 8080.

Comment: Another option - maybe you have two installations of Apache on your system?

Comment: Hi, in none of those files there is anything about port 8080

Comment: how would I find out about which servers ae running on my system?

Comment: (I tried to find a command for that earlier but couldn't)

Comment: You can search for files. Something like "find / | grep httpd"

Comment: I ran the command grep -rnw '/' -e '8080'  ... it's still running ... but I already got some results, e.g.:

Comment: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/man/man1/wsimport.1:132:Specifies an HTTP proxy server\&. The default is 8080\&.

Comment: or: /Applications/ActiveState ActiveTcl/tclvfse.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/VFS Explorer-8.5/tcltutorial/Tcl26a.html:55:socket -server accept 8080

Comment: so android studio apparently uses port 8080 to listen on ... but if android studio is not running, this shouldn't matter, right?